# How to add some days/months to date edit object to get next date?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a dateedit widget and I am getting date from that dateedit widget

```
temp_var = self.dateEdit.date() 
print(temp_var)
var_name = temp_var.toPyDate()
print(var_name)
```

this prints,

```
PyQt5.QtCore.QDate(2021, 04, 16)
2021-04-16
```

If I wanted to find next date 9 months and 9 days ahead of this date obtained from dateedit object and set another dateedit object, how can we do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QDate offers methods to add months and days:

```py
days = 9
months = 9

dt = self.dateEdit.date().addMonths(months).addDays(days)

print(dt, dt.toPyDate())
```

Comment: Aha okay @eyllanesc. Thank you !